# signup() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create signup form adding email field in django from base class UserCreationForm. The code goes as

**form.py**

```
class signup(UserCreationForm):

  email=forms.EmailField()

  class Meta:
    model=User
    fields=('username','email','password1','password2')

  def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email=(self.cleaned_data["email"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**view.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=signup(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/rgsuc')

    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form']=signup()
    return render_to_response('register.html',args)
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^accounts/signup',signup),
```

**Error**

```
\view.py in signup, line 75
signup() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I tried through this video tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaPHSlTmg1s&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD)

Comment: If you look at your `view.py`, you're doing `signup(request.POST)` in one place, and `signup()` in another. Obviously you intended one of those to create an instance of the `signup` class and the other to call the `signup` function, but which one is which? How do you expect Python to guess?

Comment: As a side note, if you follow [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions, this kind of error becomes impossible, because a CapWordsNamed class can never have the same name as a lower_underscore_named function.

Comment: @abarnert, `signup` form class (maybe the descendant of django forms.Form) constructor accepts post data optionally. So I think both `signup(request.POST)` and `signup()` was intended to call `signup` class.

Comment: @falsetru: OK, in that case, the problem is simpler. Sometimes I'm no smarter than a dumb Python interpreter. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code uses same name for the view(`def signup(request):`) and the form class (`class signup(UserCreationForm)`); cause `signup` call in the view call the view itself, not the form class.

Use different names.

Comment: yes, the form showed the email field and signup the email but it is not entered into database of user when viewed form admin panel. how could we bind the form data to database?

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya, Post another separated question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the error says, your problem is that you call `args['form']=signup()`, when you already defined `def signup(request):`, where you declared that you want the `signup` function to take a request.  If you are trying to create a signup object from form.py, you first need to add (at the top of view.py) `import form` and then refer to it as `form.signup()`, and that should work, I believe.